# Save a tensorflow model after a fixed training time

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm training a model on a server that allows me only one hour of computation: At the end of that time, it will simply kill my job. I would like tensorflow to save the results of its training after, say, 58 minutes of training, no matter what is the current state. I'm OK with it saving the status at the last completed epoch, I just want to have an idea what's going on. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course, you can define a callback function delegated to stop the training phase.

You can have a look here for further information:
https://towardsdatascience.com/neural-network-with-tensorflow-how-to-stop-training-using-callback-5c8d575c18a9

In this example, is created a callback function in order to stop the training phase when the 'ACCURACY' exceeds the threshold. You can modify the function in order to make a time computation in order to verify the elapsed time.

---

This is a working piece of code:

```py
class TimeOut(Callback):
    def __init__(self, t0, timeout):
        super().__init__()
        self.t0 = t0
        self.timeout = timeout  # time in minutes

    def on_train_batch_end(self, batch, logs=None):
        if time.time() - self.t0 > self.timeout * 60:  # 58 minutes
            print(f"\nReached {(time.time() - self.t0) / 60:.3f} minutes of training, stopping")
            self.model.stop_training = True

callbacks = [TimeOut(t0=time.time(), timeout=58)]
```

Comment: Thank you Alessio. Is there a cleaner way of accessing the elapsed time than assigning `t0 = time.time()` and checking `time.time() - t0` ? Maybe tensorflow / keras already has some time variable?

Comment: tf/ keras doesn't have a time variable. Even if it did it would probably just be a call to time.time() and if it's not then you can't trust it in the same way you can trust this callback - this definitely the best solution. I'd recommend it gets included, a time based callback is really useful

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Pythonanywhere installed tensorflow-addons just fine but wouldn't import it, and I needed something like its timestopping. Many, many thanks for this solution!

Answer (score 0):

Tensorflow has recently made an addon that does exactly this.

In your case it would look something like this

```
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

time_stopping_callback = tfa.callbacks.TimeStopping(seconds=60*58, verbose=1) #58min

model.fit(........, callbacks = [time_stopping_callback])
```

Link:
https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/tutorials/time_stopping