# Tensorflow: How to train for a length of time instead of epochs?

Tags: python, tensorflow

Prior research: 
[Most relevant tensorflow article](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/train_and_evaluate) 
[How can I calculate the time spent for overall training a model in Tensorflow (for all epochs)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75419926/how-can-i-calculate-the-time-spent-for-overall-training-a-model-in-tensorflow-f) 
[Show Estimated remaining time to train a model Tensorflow with large epochs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58593921/show-estimated-remaining-time-to-train-a-model-tensorflow-with-large-epochs)

Code:

```
y = to_categorical(self.ydata, num_classes=self.vocab_size)
model = Sequential()
model.add(Embedding(self.vocab_size, 10, input_length=1))
model.add(LSTM(1000, return_sequences=True))
model.add(LSTM(1000))
model.add(Dense(1000, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(self.vocab_size, activation="softmax"))
keras.utils.plot_model(model, show_layer_names=True)
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(modelFilePath, monitor='loss', verbose=1,save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
reduce = ReduceLROnPlateau(monitor='loss', factor=0.2,patience=3, min_lr=0.0001, verbose=1)
tensorboard_Visualization = TensorBoard(log_dir=logdirPath)
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(lr=0.001))
history = model.fit(self.Xdata, y, epochs=epochs, batch_size=64, callbacks=[checkpoint, reduce, tensorboard_Visualization]).history
```

Inspiration from:

1. https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2021/08/predict-the-next-word-of-your-text-using-long-short-term-memory-lstm/
2. https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-next-word-predictor-in-tensorflow-e7e681d4f03f

This code takes a list of one-word "questions" and "answers" to train. Impressive background knowledge if you guessed the model's goals before reading this. Anyways, this code works. I'm looking only to enhance it at this point.

How can I train a model for a set amount of time? The time an epoch takes varies based on what text I feed this AI. It changes a lot, generally around 10 seconds to 4 minutes. I could use that to approximate epochs from time, but if another way exists, I would appreciate a more concrete idea from TensorFlow's resources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's imperative to define a timeout the way you formulated the problem, then take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58096219/save-a-tensorflow-model-after-a-fixed-training-time)

However, accuracy will greatly change based on the text you'll feed it. From extremely poor, to overfitted. So you'd end up spending more time just to verify. A better fit for your problem would be a custom [EarlyStopping](https://towardsdatascience.com/a-practical-introduction-to-early-stopping-in-machine-learning-550ac88bc8fd).

```
from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import EarlyStopping

custom_early_stopping = EarlyStopping(
    monitor='val_accuracy', 
    patience=8, 
    min_delta=0.001, 
    mode='max'
)

history = model.fit(
    # rest of parameters
    callbacks=[custom_early_stopping ] # and rest of callbacks
)
```

In this example you set validation accuracy as performance monitor to determine when to stop the training. I don't think you'd have any use for a low accuracy trained model, or to continue after you hit it just because you set a time.

`patience=8` means the training is terminated as soon as 8 epochs with no improvement. `min_delta=0.001` means the validation accuracy has to improve by at least 0.001 for it to count as an improvement. `mode='max'` means it will stop when the quantity monitored has stopped increasing.

Comment: Tested. This is great, I appreciate the help!